# Load unpacked Chrome extension - how does it know where my index.html file is?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome Extension project, the structure looks like this:

```
project/
  dist/
    index.html
  manifest.json
```

When I go More Tools -> Extensions -> Load Unpacked Extensions

I choose the root of the project, and it works! But I can't figure out how it knows to load `dist/index.html`? The `manifest.json` file doesn't say anything about `dist/index.html`, so how does Chrome know how to load the extension?

I built this extension a few months ago, and now I can't figure out how it works lol.

the `manifest.json` file looks like this verbatim:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Suman Generator",
  "description": "This extension allows the user to generate test skeletons.",
  "version": "1.223",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "options_ui": {
    "page": "options.html",
    "chrome_style": true
  },
  "devtools_page": "aspects/dev-tools/dist/suman-dev-tools.html",
  "optional_permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "management",
    "activeTab",
    "webNavigation",
    "storage",
    "*://*/",
    "http://*/",
    "https://*/",
    "background",
    "browser",
    "tabs",
    "identity",
    "identity.email",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/",
    "pageAction",
    "notifications",
    "clipboard",
    "clipboardWrite",
    "clipboardRead",
    "unlimitedStorage",
    "webRequest",
    "userinfo",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    {
      "socket": [
        "tcp-connect:*:*"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "modal-iframe.html"
  ],
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/icon16.png",
    "48": "icons/icon48.png",
    "128": "icons/icon128.png"
  },
  "omnibox": {
    "keyword": "suman:chrome"
  },
  "oauth2": {
    "client_id": "5461307462-7geu9374.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "scopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chromewebstore.readonly"
    ]
  },
  "key": "MIIBC57LwMgUdRxfY4I40oAiKy57o3tWF/A1BrTNY0nQIDAQAB",
  "short_name": "Suman Short Name",
  "offline_enabled": true,
  "background": {
    "page": "background.html",
    "persistent": true
  },
  "content_scripts": [],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://plus.google.com 'unsafe-inline' 'http' 'https' 'unsafe-eval' '*'; object-src '*';"
}
```

Comment: The question is incomplete: who/what/where loads or references  index.html? It may be quicker if you share the complete zip of your extension.

Comment: You want a zip file of the extension?

Comment: That is the question - how does Chrome know how to load my extension if I just point Chrome to the root of the project? It will know where the manifest.json file is, because that's in the root of the project. But the manifest.json file says nothing about dist/index.html

Comment: Can you upload the whole extension project in github so we can take a look?

Comment: My point of clarification is how index.html is involved in your question? Why do you think it's loaded? What **exactly** happens? Since you didn't provide these details, I asked for the entire source code so we can look at it.

Comment: Most likely the background script sets/invokes the popup programmatically.

Comment: @wOxxOm yes I think you are right, that's probably what it is, good call